# Export coded UI test to TFS

Tags: c#, testing, tfs, coded-ui-tests

I can create new tests in `MS Test Manager` and they work fine. But the problem is it hasn't assertions (i.e. to check UI controls' values). To add assertions I create a new test project in my solution in `Visual Studio 2012` and I add a new `CodedUITest`. Then I import a test (action recording) from `TFS`. And now it's possible to change the `C#` code and run test from `Visual Studio`. But how to export the changes I made in the code into `Team Foundation Server` (to make them visible/available for other users)? Is it possible?

Comment: just check in your new soloution

Comment: When I check it in it will be pushed into my TFS repo, but what if I want it to synchronize with my MS Test Manager? Is it possible?

Comment: I haven't started using TM yet, so i don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't synchronize with Test Manager. But you have to use different Approach. When your Testers Record Tests in MTM, you can retrieve it using Coded UI Tests. Don't change the Coded UI test code, instead create the object of coded UI test class and change properties and call corresponding Coded UI methods in your Test Method.

Once done, the testers can associate your Test Method in the Test Case. More details here => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx

Comment: That is the correct link, but the text description of what is in the link is horribly wrong....

Comment: Sorry that link explains only the final bit. Associating automated tests with the test case. I couldn't find any link which explains the whole MTM to coded UI test and back to MTM flow. If you have any better link, please share. Thanks.

Comment: Re-reading it it makes more sense, although I'm not sure about the first line. Are you trying to say that you can't synchronize an Action Recording with a Coded UI test? That's true I suppose, as it is more of a migration than a sync. But why not change the Coded UI test code? Doing so doesn't change the workflow; you can still associate the coded UI test to the test case in MTM.

Comment: Yea the flow still works. but When you re record or edit your coded ui steps, all the coded ui class changes will disappear. So that's why I said its better to write your changes in your test method. Hope I am clear about what I am saying.